# Excel combining text results -> #N/B if referred cell isn't deleted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list with Vlookup. But when I want to combine less than 4 answers in a single cell, i get #N/A. I have to delete the Vlookup cells in order to get this right.
I have a range of 1 to 4 answers.

=M70 & " - " &N70& " - " &O70& " - " &P70

The 4 cells above are cells which contain a Vlookup function.

But sometimes i only require for example M70 & N70 only.
Then I need to delete the Vlookup cells O70 and P70 to make it display without #N/A

How can i make it so i don't have to delete those cells? with an IFERROR perhaps?

[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W7Yw.png)

Comment: Try `=concatenate(...;...;...;...;...;...)`

Comment: I tried this:
=concatenate(M70;N70;O70;P70)
But still I get #N/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may use the IF() function in combination with ISNA(). Something like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(M70),"",M70) & IF(ISNA(N70),"","-"&N70) ...
```

hope this helps!

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-isna-function

Answer (score 0):

If one has `TEXTJOIN()` you could use:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",,IF(ISNA(M70:P70),"",M70:P70))
```

This would skip empty values. If you don't want that than change the second parameter to `0`.

Also, note that without ExcelO365 (Thus Excel2019) you'll need to enter this formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Also, you could use an `IFERROR` on the source formulas themselves to show blank cells instead of altering the follow-up concatenation.

Comment: When i enter this exactly as you described i get the message that it says i don't have enough arguments input. It seems like the second part M70:P70 doesnt work

Comment: It does work, just not on Excel 2013 I'm afraid. You'll need Excel 2019 or ExcelO365